# Best way to manage multiple users on mobile dashboard

Tags: information-architecture

I am designing a mobile dashboard which needs to allow the admin user to manage anything from 20 - 100 sub users.

For each of the sub users, there are multiple possible actions EG: pay bill, analyse bill, update log in details, ETC. The actions could easily span too many categories to be on one page.

Would it be best to get the admin user to select the sub user in question and proceed from there as a top level task, and then select from a task, or choose the task first, and then the user.

If the task is chosen first, this means the admin user would have to sort though many users for nearly every single task on the dashboard.

I have tried to find mobile apps dealing with multiple users for inspiration but am struggling to find any as of yet.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the answer, I would encourage you to talk to the admin first and find out (1) their current daily workflow managing users, (2) their pain points performing such tasks and (3) any hacks they currently use to make their work easier.

In my case, similar projects needs in the past did indicate them preferring both ways of managing users. The 2 approaches satisfy different use cases: (1) Managing one user vs (2) Batch management.

Single user management seems to be a must because users are individuals, each with their own issues and personal information. As for batch management, I would look into clues of whether current admins automate or "batch" their work in any way. That may give you a bit of confidence whether such a feature would actually be used.

Answer (score 0):

Create a layer of abstraction between users and responsibilities.

Create groups. Map multiple users to a group. You could make use of dragndrop material chips to create groups or have multiple chip selection and change colour of chip on touch. Something like Facebook's tag mechanism.

Then easily match group to responsibility using a multiselect drop-down with auto complete feature.

Answer (score 0):

Having 1, 2, or both will depend on how the users you are designing it for use. If you have access to them it would be good to look for different use cases the admins do on the go which needs to be optimises for on mobile. Features which need to be on mobile vs which should be on desktop only.

For services see if you could group them into commonly used buckets and simplify service selection. Allow admin to be able to drill down to a specific service when required.